# Why does $n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!=n!(n+2)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Why does $n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!=n!(n+2)^2$?

Note: This is from the [1984 ARML I-7](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1052h984924s3_arml_individual_questions_1984).

Comment: Note:  $(k+1)!=(k+1)\cdot k!$ is one of the defining properties of the factorial.  Rewrite the above where the **only** factorials appearing are $n!$ and combine like terms.

Comment: $$  n! \; \left( 1 + (n+1) + (n+1)(n+2) \right) $$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align*}
 n! + (n+1)! + (n+2)! &= n! + n!(n+1) + n!(n+1)(n+2) \\
&=n!(1 + (n+1) + (n+1)(n+2))\\
&= n!(n^2 + 4n + 4) = n!(n+2)^2\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Wait if you factor $(n+1)!$ it becomes $n!(n+1)$? Where can I learn how to manipulate equations with factorials? (online, free)

Comment: @suomynonA: $$(n+1)!=(n+1)\underbrace{(n)(n-1)\ldots(2)(1)}_{n!}=(n+1)n!$$

Comment: @suomynonA: I wouldn't call it "factor", it's just using the definition. The number $(n+1)!$ is by definition the product of the numbers $1, \dots, n, n + 1$ so we can write it as $(n+1)$ times the product of the numbers $1, \dots, n$ leading to $(n+1)! = (n+1) \cdot n!$. Often this is given as a (recursive) definition of $n!$.

Comment: @Brian and levap - Thanks, I see it now. Can someone answer the second part of my comment?

Comment: @suomynonA: Sorry, I'm not aware of any such places online. You might find some relevant information in Khan's academy but I'm not really familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

$$n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!=n!+n!(n+1)+n!(n+1)(n+2)\\=n![1+(n+1)+(n+1)(n+2)]\\=n![(n+2)+(n+1)(n+2)]=n!(n+2)(n+1+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

Because you can  factor $n!$:
\begin{align}n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!&=n![1+(n+1)+(n+1)(n+2)]=n![n+2+(n+1)(n+2)]\\
&=n![(n+2)(1+(n+1)]=n! (n+2)^2.\end{align}

Comment: How did you get the first part?

Comment: I lost the starting point on copying-pasting. I've added it. Thanks for pointing it!